# Problem loading pdf output ggsave on the HPC: any better package or better format?

Tags: r, ggplot2, hpc

I have problem loading pdf output generated by ggsave on the HPC. I was wondering if there is any better package work with ggplot2 in this context or better format to save the output?

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: What is "the HPC"?

Comment: High-performance computing on the cluster.

Comment: @PoGibas I can not load the pdf output on local computer after I transfer the output from the cluster.